# How do i make an activity open up a fragment?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a fragment called Chap.java and an activity called Exercise.java.
I managed to get the fragment Chap.java to open up the activity Exercise.java.
But is there a way for me this to do this the other way round?
I mean get the activity to open up the fragment.

Here's my current code:

My Chap.java

```
package com.boszcorp.newbuttontestcrezi;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import static com.boszcorp.newbuttontestcrezi.R.layout.chapter;

/**
 * Created by Aizad on 23/03/2015.
 */
public class Chap extends Fragment {
    View rootview;

    @Nullable

    //@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(chapter, container, false);
        Button newPage = (Button)rootview.findViewById(R.id.buttonEx);
        newPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Exercise.class);
        startActivity(intent);




    }
});
        return rootview;};
}
```

My Exercise.java

```
package com.boszcorp.newbuttontestcrezi;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by Aizad on 23/03/2015.
 */
public class Exercise extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.exercise);
        Button newReturn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonChap);
        newReturn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (Exercise.this, Chap.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Can I know. What is your exact issue.

Comment: You are not able to open fragment from Activity?

Comment: @Kesh1234 yes im trying to open a fragment from activity but when i press the button the app crashes

Comment: @Sakitaro can you post stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Use this code within onClick():

```
Chap mChap = new Chap();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager() or getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, mChap);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Hope this will work..

Comment: what do i fill the (R.id.content_frame) with?

Comment: This is your FrameLayout id.

Comment: i dont understand sry

Comment: I hope you use this type of code in your xml file:

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

Comment: its underlined by squiggly red line and it says cannot be applied

Comment: If you want to open a Fragment then you have to first create a xml file.

Within it you have to put that <FrameLayout> code.

Then you can use that code

Comment: Please follow this reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Try this:

```
Chap fragment = new Chap();
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager(); //or getFragmentManager() if you are not using support library.
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.your_container, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, create a new class which extends activity and do the following in your new class:

set the content view of the new class to the layout of fragment and add the following code:

```
Chap f1 = new Chap();       
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_detail, f1).commit();
```

Hope this helps you.